# Recommend resolution for the error: OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED : The identity provider configuration is disabled

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-api

Can someone please recommend a resolution to the problem that I am facing in my firebase web application where I am trying out google oath.

here is the snippet of code:

```
//login with google

    const googleButton = document.querySelector('#googleLogin');
    googleButton.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
        loginForm.reset();

        const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result){
            console.log(result);
            console.log("Successful Google Sign in");


        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
            console.log("Login failed");
```

here is the response payload that I get from the browser:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED : The identity provider configuration is disabled.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED : The identity provider configuration is disabled.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Instead of a `Successful Google Sign in` from the console log, i get :

> Storage access automatically granted for tracker “https://nompu-website.firebaseapp.com” on “http://127.0.0.1:5500”.

I have enabled Google as one of the sign in options.

Comment: Are you sure you enabled the sign-in method from your Firebase Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted the browser, re-ran the web-application , enabled the Google sign-in method from Firebase console (again) and finally  added the authorized domain (127.0.0.0) of type custom to the list of authorized domains. It worked.