# Firebase Authenticate Error - whenever i try to signin with google

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am testing Firebase auth google on localhost, but I get the following error:

> {code: "auth/operation-not-allowed", message: "The identity provider configuration is disabled."}
>
> code: "auth/operation-not-allowed"
> message: "The identity provider configuration is disabled."

```
function googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        const user = result.user;
        document.write('Hello ${user.displayName}');
        console.log(user)
    })
    .catch(console.log)

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58064403/recommend-resolution-for-the-error-operation-not-allowed-the-identity-provide

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to enable the Google sign-in provider in the Firebase console, for your project. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error

Open the Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/project), choose your project, click on the "Authentication" vertical menu item, click on the "Sign-in method" tab and, then, activate the Google sign-in provider.